# Нужно ли выделять запятыми "словно век" и "как мгновенье" и почему? Мгновенья длятся словно век, и век проходит как мгновенье

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Якобы эта строка из стихотворения Фета (так указано в учебнике русского языка за 8 класс, автор Бархударов), однако мне не удалось найти это стихотворение.
С одной стороны, запятые нужны, т.к. есть сравнительные обороты, с другой стороны, можно так рассудить, что они по смыслу тесно связаны со сказуемыми и без них сказуемые кажутся неполными.

Comment: Любопытно, что я все-такие кое-что нашла, связанное с этими строками. Это была статья, посвященная памяти Шанского. Автор статьи ссылается на следующее издание: Н.М. Шанский. Любовь и долг – надежных два крыла (стихи разных лет). Москва: ЭкоПресс-2000, 2002. Получается, что это строчки Н.М.Шанского. Согласно статье, только в первом случае есть запятая. «Когда темнеет в голове
И не вздохнуть от вдохновенья,
Мгновенье длится, словно век,
И век проходит как мгновенье.
Ты пишешь обо всем, чем ты
В мгновенье это переполнен,
И снова прежние мечты
О сердце бьются, словно волны…»

Comment: Может, в качестве мгновения?

Comment: В общем, как я понял за последние несколько недель, что если вы не хотите ставить запятую - не ставьте, но и читать тогда нужно без остановки и в утвердительном(предикативном) ключе: мгновенье длится слово век - то есть, мгновенье есть век, без остановки с акцентом на слове Век, и Век и тд. То есть можно даже с большой буквы написать Век, имя мгновения есть Век, нареку мгновение Веком. А если запятую ставить, то нужно делать интонацию остановки и сравнения, но у Фета, правильнее, как мне кажется, интонационно. Ну и словно волны венчает мысль, поэтому это просто сравнение, через как с запятой.

Comment: Правильно вы поняли:  (1) МгновЕнья длятся,  словно вЕк, и вЕк проходит, как мгновЕнье. Ударением выделены существительные, которые сравниваются. (2) Мгновения длятся словно вЕк, и век проходит как мгновЕнье

Comment: @Sharon именно это я и хотел сказать, хотя переврал фразу по пути и слишком усложнил. В речи эти акценты слышны и понимаются интуитивно, а при письме могут менять то, как нужно воспринимать текст. Короче, вслух нужно читать, не только смотреть на слова и знаки препинания.

Comment: Согласна с вами. А я вот уже семь лет это рассказываю, а меня только ругают:)) Может, вас теперь послушают.

Comment: Для такого параллелизма (ударения на "мгновенья и "век") нужен тот же глагол. Не звучит. Сравнить: *МгновЕния длятся — словно вЕк, а вЕк длится — как мгновЕнье.* Ну и тире в таких случаях. Здесь похоже на то, что обороты входят в сказуемые.